# (function(){})() vs. !function(){}()

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, plugins

In jQuery javascript code I see

```
(function(window, undefined) {
})(window);
```

And in Twitter

```
!function(window, undefined) {
}(window);
```

Can someone tell what the difference between these two approaches is?

Comment: It's actually vanilla JavaScript code, no jQuery there.

Comment: I know.. what I meant is where this approach is used. Now I know that the !function approach is used to save one byte.

Answer (score 1):

Using the ! operator before the function causes it to be treated as an expression, so we can call it:

```
!function() {}()
```

http://jasonlau.biz/home/faq/what-is-the-exclamation-mark-used-for-in-code

Comment: Thank you. In the answer in above mentioned question I see that it is used to save some space.. :)